# DialogFlow v2 Access Token cannot generate

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, dialogflow-es

With version 1 this is how I used to communicate with DialogFlow Api!

```
fetch(configs.baseUrl + "query?v=20150910", {
    body: JSON.stringify({query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "somerandomthing"}),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + configs.accessToken,
    },
    method: 'POST',
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.result.fulfillment.speech);
        return data.result.fulfillment.speech;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

I simply had to pass the access token into header and that was it!

I dont know how can I make this code work with DialogFlow v2, I am getting stuck on the access token, one my V2 Agents I can not longer see access token but instead I have a  Project Id and Service Account.

I manage to create Service key from google console and activate thru gcloud but I just dont know where to get or how to generate this access token, or do I need an access token into v2, if not, how do I deal with this?

A working example would much appreciated.

Note I have downloaded this file which contains these kind of data and used this file in gcloud and it said that service activated smth but then what?
is that all? what should I do next so I can make http call to V2 DialogFlow.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxx",
  "client_email": "xxxx",
  "client_id": "xxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/dialogflow-client%40xxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did pretty much the right thing, but you would probably want to use Dialogflows [Node.js client SDK](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2). These SDKs read the authentication JSON file automatically when you instantiate a client (see [the example](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2#using-the-client-library) on Github, the file is read by `... = new dialogflow.SessionsClient()`).

Comment: can I use the nodejs client code without doing things like node server.js I mean can I just integrate nodejs code into my html jquery code? Seems like I only need to use Node.js just to gain constant access token. WOuld it be possible to gain access token without using node js at all?

Comment: Is it possible that your confusing the [Dialogflow API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest) with the [Dialogflow Webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment)? The first one is used to manage the agent itself (update intents, entities etc.), the latter to actually fulfill user requests. The Dialogflow API does provide an endpoint to process a normal user query (`/query` in V1), but that is only intended for developing and testing. Your actual fulfillments service must answer POST requests from the Dialogflow Webhook, for which it doesn't need a token.

Answer (score 2):

Below is another example of creating your DialogFlow V2 access token using Node.js. The library that is used in the code below is [google-oauth-jwt](https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt).

```js
const googleAuth = require('google-oauth-jwt');

function generateAccessToken() {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  googleAuth.authenticate(
   {
    email: <client_email>,
    key: <private_key>,
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
   },
   (err, token) => {
    resolve(token);
   },
  );
 });
}
```

You may find your `client_email` and `private_key` from the JSON key file you have downloaded from your Google Cloud Platform project's service account page. If you are unsure how/where to download it, you may checkout my blog post [here](https://www.geboto.io/2018/06/02/how-to-generate-dialogflow-v2-access-token-programmatically-with-node-js/).

To find out which scope which scope you may need, you may checkout the DialogFlow V2 REST API documentation [page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest).

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

Comment: On the page you linked it says a limited number of Google Clouds support API_KEYS and it does not list DialogFlow as one of them.