# Oauth2 - get access token, server to access Google-Cloud-platform

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

The Oauth2 documentation for google doesnt contain (that I have seen yet)
Information on what I am trying to do.

From my server I want to post request to my google cloud to get a response.

For this I need an access token, currently i'm taking it manually from the playground. I am going from my server to my cloud and the documentation states about a user accepting access and then being redirected etc but I don't involve any users.

- I need to continuously, automatically get an access token for my requests, or similar. Without needing to click for access?

this is the request, for context:

```
var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/someproject/agent/sessions/1:detectIntent',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.GlsGBscelmqeHgOVgx1p4EF_L45zetym6s3isC1HF4IYJqb20vHd8FolxvsmM_vU2fmIPWN3JElGIEuNN3i_-N9V-68YlwNvEduMIA5SuSltK-Sepsl0yNYM9REy',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            "queryInput": {
                "event": {
                    "name": "Matching",
                    "languageCode": "en"
                }
            }
        },
        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
    };
```

For more information, I am triggering an intent from dialogflow.

Comment: Could you find a solution to that? It would be nice, if you come back and document your final solution here, so everyone can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application does not involve user interaction, and if you would like to automate the authentication method, you should use [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount), notably, you could use the JSON Web Token (JWT) or the Google ID Access token to authenticate between services.

For more information in this regard, you may follow this article in [the GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication).

You may also find useful information in this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625189/dialogflow-v2-access-token-cannot-generate). It offers help on how to pass a token through DialogFlow.