# How to send POST request to Dialogflow using v2 APIs of Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I want to send a request to Dialogflow using the POST API. I'm am using v2 of the Dialogflow API.

My POST REQUEST IS -

https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/test-project/agent/sessions/34567:detectIntent?fields=queryResult&key=c65fe9bf355678ghjk

ERROR RECEIVED -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

I generated service account credentials and downloaded the JSON file. But I don't know how to authenticate my post request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DialogFlow v2 Access Token cannot generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625189/dialogflow-v2-access-token-cannot-generate)